# how to prevent a user control to get the datacontext, when it's hidden?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a wpf-mvvm application.

I have a base class - baseViewModel...

and two other classes, which inherit this base class

```
 class aVM : baseViewModel
    {
       public string a {get;set;}
    }

    class bVM : baseViewModel
    {
      public string b {get;set;}
    }
```

And another class- as main viewmodel - which bind to main view.

```
   Class MainVM
   {
     public baseViewModel CurrentViewSource  {get;set;}
   }
```

Also In XAML file (view) - I have two user controls. But the data context of both of these are same public property - CurrentViewSource - this is of type - baseViewModel.

```
<---MainView start DataContext="MainVM" ----->

<---user control 1 satrt----->
  <--DataContext = "CurrentViewSource " -->
  // Here CurrentViewSource  is of type aVM
<---user control 1 end ----->

<---user control 2 start----->
  <-- DataContext = "CurrentViewSource " -->
  // Here CurrentViewSource  is of type bVM   
<---user control 2 end----->

<---MainView end----->
```

I need to display one user control  at a time..and other to hide.

As both user controls (UC) uses same data context variable "CurrentViewSource",

If UC1 is visible (UC2 hidden) - CurrentViewSource will be of type aVM...and UC2 (even though hidden)..uses this as datacontext ..and is not able to see string b .

...Visual Studio shows some binding issues. please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ContentPresenter` in combination with implicit [Data Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

So, in your main view, in place where you would show one or another user control, use a ContentPresenter and bind its `Content` property to `CurrentViewSource`:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentViewSource}"/>
```

Now, for each supported view model type, define a `DataTemplate` in the resources of your main view:

```
<Window ...>
   <Window.Resources>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:aVM}">
          <my:aUserControl/>
       </DataTemplate>

       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:bVM}">
          <my:bUserControl/>
       </DataTemplate>
   </Window.Resources>
...
   <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentViewSource}"/>
...
</Window>
```

This way, whenever `CurrentViewSource` is changed, the appropriate `DataTemplate` will be applied.